# Css Background Image Not Displaying Correctly On A Mobile Device

Tags: android, css, iphone, media-queries, background-image

```
.header {
     background: #15181f url(images/bg-header.jpg) repeat; 
     color: #fff;
}
.footer {
     background: #15181f url(images/bg-footer.jpg) repeat;
     color: #fff;
}
```

Hey guys,

my header and footer background image not displaying correctly on mobile devices like android or iPhone, same goes for the iPad, the background image for header and footer is not getting displayed correctly, resulting in a cropped background image.

I tried with javascript and css, and technique after technique, but nothing works. It is neither one nor the other of these styles work on my [WordPress website](http://www.awebdesign.co.uk/) www.awebdesign.co.uk and I don't know what do with my mobile site anymore. I tried `overflow-x: hidden;` but did not want to do anything.

Tried these styles below

```
.header {
     width:100%;
     float:left;
     height:100%;
     display:block;
     position:relative;
     margin: 0 auto !important;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     z-index:10;
}
```

I also tired the following for the footer, but deleted it later because it didn't do anything good:

```
footer.footer {
     width:100%;
     float:left;
     height:100%;
     display:block;
     position:relative;
     margin: 0 auto !important;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     z-index:10;
}
```

Than I've implemented media queries,

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px
```

and later changed to this,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) 
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) 
@media screen and (min-width: 981px) and (max-width: 1024px)
```

However, it displays only the starting position of a background image on the left side. It doesn't display correctly across horizontal line, it displays vertically rather than horizontally. Please help me to find a solution to this problem and consequently learn how to apply CSS background image properties to both mobile and tablets (portrait or landscape).

I think my question is clear but if you have any questions, feel free to to ask, and I hope that others find this helpful too. Thanks in advance!

I deleted the CSS code above to clear my custom styles, the document structure, an HTML5 page, and classes will now look something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel_1"></div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="middle">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="full_width"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>           
    </section><!-- .middle -->
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="footer-nav"> 
          </div>      
        </div>        
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>

.container {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.panel_1 {background:url(images/panel_0.jpg) left top no-repeat;
          width: 940px;
          height: 270px; /*border: 1px solid #09F;*/}

section.middle {background: #CCC; clear: both;} 

.header {
    background: #15181f url(images/bg-header.jpg) repeat;
    color: #fff;
}
footer.footer { 
    background: #15181f url(images/bg-footer.jpg) repeat;
    color: #fff;
}
footer.footer {padding: 36px 0; clear: both;}
.footer-nav {float: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up the value `cover` with `contain`.

Contain will make your images snap to the width of the viewport and not scale them up until they meet the bottom of the element they are residing in.

Hope this helps. =)

Comment: Hi Marco, I changed the value from 'cover' to 'contain' you can see it live now but it doesn't do anything on mobile devices. Thanks.